# Setup multi slash in domain in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I want to set up domain with multi-slash for site root node, but it is not allowed by Umbraco. e.g.

a.com/en/uk  (example only). via Manage hostnames menu

The reason is that I have multi-lingual, and multi-domain sites, each of which is a root node. Each domain has specific region site. version 4.11

Any idea?

**Update**

It allows only one slash in the domain. Why does it not allow more than one slash? I have changed it on the Domain table directly, It seems working. Is there any implication on this.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the domains settings in Umbraco are specifically for the root domains.

However, if you think about how Umbraco allows you to organise your content structure, you could create a homepage with the root domain (e.g. yoursite.com) and then have a page for en/ and a page beneath that for uk/, in other words the UK homepage.

You could then use some server side logic to catch all requests to the root page and 301 redirect them to the UK homepage.